# Get MAC using scapy and an IP

Tags: python, linux, get, scapy, arp

I'm sending an ARP request using this line and what I basically want is to get the MAC from what's returned:

```
result = sr(ARP(op=ARP.who_has, psrc='X.X.X.X', pdst='Y.Y.Y.Y'))
```

how would I retrieve the mac from result[0]?

Answer (score 2):

You can print the target hardware address like this:

```
print result[0][ARP].hwsrc
```

Comment: On windows scapy version `2.4.0` I don't seem to have `hwsrc` as an attribute.